# Bluetooth through internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, bluetooth

Maybe it's silly but I'll ask anyway.

I have two android phones and a game which lets you play together with bluetooth.

Is there a software that can link 2 PC and bridge the two bluetooth connections through internet?

Something like: Device1 <-[bluetooth]-> PC1 <-[internet]-> PC2 <-[bluetooth]-> Device2.

Of course this should be transparent for the devices.

Comment: Did you forget the link?

Comment: Here is that link http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/sharing-internet-from-pc-to-netbook-with-bluetooth/03975490-cbad-4768-b9ef-4d6c1a7c474f  it seems you have not researched internet sharing over a Bluetooth connection.

Comment: You didn't understand my question, I don't want to share an internet connection by bluetooth. I want to commect two devices that can only communicate through bluetooth even if they are very distant by using 2 PC connected to internet to cover the gap.

Comment: I don't care about the devices connecting to the internet. I have an android phone, and my friend has an android phone but is in another country. Now, the game supports multiplayer through bluetooth but obviously we can't connect that way. So, what I hoped to do is connect my phone to my pc with bluetooth, have my friend connect his phone to his pc through bluetooth, and have the 2 PC communicate through the internet, letting the phones believe they are connected instead to the other device. I can't say it clearer than this.

Comment: If they devices are unable to connect to the same network what you want is not possible.

Comment: @Ramhound: I'm sure the latency would be horrible, but what if there was a program running on both PCs that took the data packets sent via Bluetooth from the source phone, transferred them via the internet, received them on the other PC and sent the packets to the destination phone via Bluetooth? To the destination phone it would seem as if the packets just came from the attached Bluetooth device i.e. the PC, whereas actually they would have originated from the source phone. I'm not an ISO/OSI expert, but is this not theoretically possible at least? (No idea about practical implementation.)

Comment: @Karan that's what I was thinking. Actually latency isn't really a problem since the game is turn-based.

Comment: @キキジキ: Well as per my limited understanding I don't see why it wouldn't be possible, but whether there's *actually* an app implementing this is another matter altogether. I don't suppose this is a very common request.